# SSL/DNS Connection Issue: Too Many Redirections

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, docker, python, django

I have a problem connecting to my VPS server using domain name. I installed SSL certificate on my Debian 10 Docker server and https works only with IP address, when I try to connect with domain name it says 503 Backend Not Found. I tried to do it without nginx and now I configured it with nginx and I am at the moment when it says "Too many redirects". I tried a lot of solutions but I haven't found anything similar to this.

Here is my nginx.conf script:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream web {
        server web:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name domain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - web
    restart: on-failure
```

How to properly run an SSL server on a domain?

Comment: Check the actual redirects. It's probably your backend server which sends a redirect back to http.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have a domain in the OVH service and in the DNS zone I have defined A records for the IPv4 address of the SSL certificate and AAAA record for the IPv6 address of the SSL certificate. The domain is assigned to a VPS server, also in the OVH service. The ping command to the domain name returns the IP address of the SSL certificate. What exact redirect should I create?

Comment: Check the HTTP redirects. You shouldn't create one but possibly remove it. Redirection is a concept of HTTP, so don't touch your DNS.

Comment: Also, Debian 10 will be at EoL in a couple of months, in June 2024.

Comment: @EsaJokinen In redirect in OVH from domain name, should I set redirect to SSL Certificate IP or Server IP?

Comment: No, you shouldn't.

Comment: Several red flags: 1) Did you use privacy tabs of your browser for testing? 2) When you "try to connect with domain name it says 503 Backend Not Found", how did you install the certificate on this Debian machine? That's key information missing. 3) You "tried a lot of solutions" but did you ever restore the machine to a stable state so that others can help review? Is the current `nginx.conf` the latest and you made no further changes on it? 4) You need to use right terms, as certificates do not have IP addreses and "Docker server" is also not commonly used.